# Java windows open up off-screen (multi monitor setup with Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, launcher, java, gui, window

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 (64 Bit) with Java 1.7.0_55 (openjdk-7-jdk:amd64, openjdk-7-jre:amd64). Most GUI Java applications start without any errors or warnings and their Icon shows up in the launcher, but their windows are nowhere to be seen. This is because they are being placed off screen (about 1 monitor width) to the right of the primary monitor. I've got two monitors, the right one being the primary one.

Some applications are not only being placed off screen, they are also weirdly sized. GeoGebra, for example, has the full height but is only a few pixels in width.

Using ALT+F7 and the arrow keys allows me to move the windows into the viewable area, but once I quit the programs and run them again, they will appear off-screen again and I have to do the procedure again.

I found [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1156919) about Java windows being misplaced, but it doesn't sound like my problem exactly. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477435/window-appears-off-screen-on-ubuntu) does sound like my problem but only workarounds (the one I came up with myself) are being suggested.

I wonder if I should file an additonal Bug Report via Launchpad or just add to the existing one? Also, is there a way to tell Ubuntu to remember the Java window's last position, so I don't have to move them in-screen by hand every single time? That would be an okay-ish workaround for the time being.

*I updated the question's text and title to reflect my newest findings.*

Comment: Just to clarify, these are known applications or ones you have written?

Comment: @dan08 Those are self-written applications. They compile and run fine on my Windows and Debian machines, though.

Comment: @dan08 I just installed GeoGebra only to find out that it will also not show (only the Launcher Icon is there, the window seems to be hiding...).

Comment: I now figured out that those applications do appear - they just appear far off-screen. Maybe that helps in identifying the problem or finding a solution / workaround?

Comment: I have similarly seen frequently seen problems with MATLAB, and the Java application (SCATTER)[http://www.esrf.eu/UsersAndScience/Experiments/CRG/BM26/SaxsWaxs/DataAnalysis/Scatter#HW%20requirements].  Often using the positioning hot-keys, e.g., `Ctrl-Alt-Left`, work to move the application.  Incredibly annoying.

Answer (score 3):

ALT+TAB, then keep TABbing until you find the application you want.

ALT-SPACE to open its menu (even if you can't see it)

Press 'M' to select “Move”, then use the mouse or arrow keys to bring window into view.

[source](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/06/02/ubuntu-how-to-move-an-application-which-is-displayed-offscreen/)

Comment: This is indeed the workaround I am using, but sadly no solution whatsoever. In fact, this gets extremely annoying and time-consuming. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Nice trick, and exactly what I was looking for for an application with a modal dialog not responding to other shortcuts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem partially, like this:

1. In System Settings, Display, disable one monitor
2. Start GeoGebra - it will occupy part of your visible screen
3. Enable the other monitor
4. Quit GeoGebra
5. Start GeoGebra with both monitors enabled

You should find it appear within the visible screen.

I have no idea why this works!!!